# How can two round buttons be displayed per line and a single one above it centered without spacing to the lower two and vice versa?

Tags: html, css, button, css-selectors, center

[image]

How can the buttons on the left side be displayed as on the right? The individual groups are separated with padding and are displayed with flow-root.

```css
.group {
  display: flow-root;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
}

button.a {
  float: left;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #8B8B8B;
}
```

```html
<div class="group"><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="group"><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? seems fairly easy given the markup

Comment: If a div tag is set for each line of buttons and `display: flex;align-items: center;justify-content: center;` is used, the buttons deform and the single button is not displayed directly next to the lower two.

Comment: there are many ways of doing this, you can remove display flow-root and float left for the buttons, set all spans to display block and text-align center, it will show what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways of doing this, here is a simple way of doing it without changing the html

EDIT: since your circles won't touch borders normally, you will need to manually push them towards their destination

```css
.group {
  float: left;
  padding: 7px 0px 7px 0px;
  clear: both;
}

span {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center
}

button.a {
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #8B8B8B;
}
.move-up {
  margin-top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="group"><span>
      <button class="a"></button>
    </span><span class="move-up">
      <button class="a"></button><button class="a"></button>
    </span><span>
      <button class="a"></button><button class="a"></button>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="group"><span>
      <button class="a"></button><button class="a"></button>
    </span><span>
      <button class="a move-up"></button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: How can the spacing for each group be removed so that the borders of the buttons touch each other?

Comment: @user8652270 updated answer to push circles closer together